# Ganymed SSH2 Jump host

Tags: java, linux, ssh

I'm using the ganymed lib to access remote hosts in my network. But, in this network has routers and switches that can only be accessed by another host.

To illustrate this, in my network there is a Linux server and connected to it there is a Cisco router. The connection to the Linux server worked, but i try to execute the command:

ssh user@ip

After this i use the session.getStdin.write() for executing another command in the session and make the login in the password prompt. But, after the execution of the first command (ssh), the program still running and doesn't send any output.

Comment: So, the one solution i find was in the Jsch lib.
I'm using it now and is working great.
If someone is having problem if Ganymed lib, search about Jsch.

Here one solution for this question using JSch lib.

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java.html